# Share Windows7 and Windows8 erro "to continue, please enter administrator password"

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, file-sharing, windows-server-2003, uac

In our network we have a Win2003
Now we try to install windows7 and windows8 for our clients,
Our client in active directory have a "Normal User"
For example: user "arab" when share one folder in PC get a windows:
UAC -> "to continue, please enter administrator password"

Comment: Your user isn't a local administrator if you are getting a UAC password dialog. You can't enable sharing unless you are an administrator.

Comment: Thanks Richard, In our network we want limited user (not install software, not change IP, and more...).
but this user should be share directory

Answer (score 0):

If you want non-administrator users to be able to share folders, you should check out [this page](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/aaron_margosis/archive/2005/04/18/409105.aspx), which details registry settings that need to be changed to allow that.

I'd personally recommend against making that change, though. Instead, use Group Policy to share `c:\users\public`, and have the users put any shared (local) files there. Create a new share through a GPO under Computer > Preferences > Windows Settings > Network Shares. Then, any user on that system can copy/save anything to `Public Documents`, and have it available `\\compname\public\documents`.

Comment: Thanks Richard, if one user need to share 10GB data for another user, this solution is not usable.